# Correct HTML element to mark up a quote including the author and date?

Tags: html

What would be the correct HTML element to encapsulate this text:

I love the smell of napalm in the morning, Kilgore, 1979.

The text includes the actual quote, the author of the quote, and the date. Due to CMS restrictions I can only put a single element around the whole text.

`<q>` appears to just be for the actual quote: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_quotation_elements.asp

`<blockquote>` is the same but longer: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_quotation_elements.asp

Comment: If you can use only one element, then try passing the text with quote:
<span>"I love the smell of napalm in the morning", Kilgore, 1979.</span>

Comment: I was hoping to use a semantic element. This is already in a div so has no layout requirements. Is there not a relevant one?

Comment: Putting it inside a <q> tag seems like the best solution given your limitations.

Comment: @Fester are you sure this would be valid? Do you have a source? I explained my reservations about this element in my question.

Comment: HTML escaping a HTML snippet is not possible as a text parameter in your CMS?

Comment: @michaPau how would that help? The CMS can only have 1 input field for my 'quote'. The 'quote' in face includes the actual quote, the source, and the date. As content is added by editors I cant be 100% sure that any exact format will be kept too. However broadly speaking it will always be for this type of formate ie a quote and some details about it.

Comment: @Evans ok, it was thinking to escape a html snippet as a workaround  - but when your CMS actually constructs the text and it's not you who enters the text this is not possibility for sure.

Comment: @Evans there are no black and white rules about what is and what isn't valid content for tags in HTML, there are only guidelines. You may be overthinking this